# A multi-threaded echo server

Tags: multithreading, sockets, server, tcl, echo

Which "thread" does this error relate to?

```
thufir@tleilax:~/wunderground$ 
thufir@tleilax:~/wunderground$ tclsh 21.12.tcl
can't read "thread": no such variable
    while executing
"thread::send -async $thread {
thread::attach $sock
fconfigure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0
fileevent $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]
SendMes..."
    (file "21.12.tcl" line 71)
thufir@tleilax:~/wunderground$
```

example code 21-12:

```
package require Tcl 8.4
package require Thread 2.5


set sock 12345
set host 127.0.0.1
#set port 7777

if {$argc > 0} {
    set port [lindex $argv 0]
} else {
    set port 9001
}

socket -server _ClientConnect $port
proc _ClientConnect {sock host port} {
}

#Tcl holds a reference to the client socket during
#this callback, so we can't transfer the channel to our
#worker thread immediately. Instead, we'll schedule an
#after event to create the worker thread and transfer
#the channel once we've re-entered the event loop.
after 0 [list ClientConnect $sock $host $port]
proc ClientConnect {sock host port} {
    #Create a separate thread to manage this client. The
    #thread initialization script defines all of the client
    #communication procedures and puts the thread in its
    #event loop.
    set thread [thread::create {
        proc ReadLine {sock} {
            if {[catch {gets $sock line} len] || [eof $sock]} {
                catch {close $sock}
                thread::release
            } elseif {$len >= 0} {
                EchoLine $sock $line
            }
        }
        proc EchoLine {sock line} {
            if {[string equal -nocase $line quit]} {
                SendMessage $sock \
                    "Closing connection to Echo server"
                catch {close $sock}
                thread::release
            } else {
                SendMessage $sock $line
            }
        }
        proc SendMessage {sock msg} {
            if {[catch {puts $sock $msg} error]} {
                puts stderr "Error writing to socket: $error"
                catch {close $sock}
                thread::release
            }
        }
        # Enter the event loop
        thread::wait
    }]


    #Release the channel from the main thread. We use
    #thread::detach/thread::attach in this case to prevent
    #blocking thread::transfer and synchronous thread::send
    #commands from blocking our listening socket thread.
    # Copy the value of the socket ID into the
    # client's thread
    thread::send -async $thread [list set sock $sock]
    # Attach the communication socket to the client-servicing
    # thread, and finish the socket setup.
}
thread::send -async $thread {
    thread::attach $sock
    fconfigure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0
    fileevent $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]
    SendMessage $sock "Connected to Echo server"
}
vwait forever
```

from:

This Chapter is from Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk, 4th Ed.
Copyright 2003 © Brent Welch, Ken Jones
http://www.beedub.com/book/

I had to add the `sock` and and `host` variables which makes me think that I'm missing more.  The name "thread" for a thread variable seems questionable (?).

Comment: After some formatting, the error doesn't really surprise me: http://paste.tclhelp.net/?id=i0f

Comment: It seems that the pasted code has the same error, line 71?

Comment: Yeah, but a syntax checker is not the worst idea.

Comment: I like tclhelp.net and am surprised that it's not built into, or on top of, an editor.  I even downloaded komodo specifically for tcl.  Yes, off topic, but certainly a good syntax checker, or, even better, **fixer** would be useful.  I see `bracelevel.tcl` but it doesn't "pretty print" or format code.

Comment: It uses naglfar under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You've managed to chew the ordering of the lines in the book just enough to make the code really not work. If we look at the [relevant chapter](http://www.beedub.com/book/4th/Threads.pdf), we see that the code *actually* says this things like this:

```
proc _ClientConnect {sock host port} {

    # Tcl holds a reference to the client socket during
    # this callback, so we can't transfer the channel to our
    # worker thread immediately. Instead, we'll schedule an
    # after event to create the worker thread and transfer
    # the channel once we've re-entered the event loop.

    after 0 [list ClientConnect $sock $host $port]
}
```

That's *much* less strange! Similarly, you've moved this block:

```
thread::send -async $thread {
    thread::attach $sock
    fconfigure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0
    fileevent $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]
    SendMessage $sock "Connected to Echo server"
}
```

outside the `ClientConnect` procedure, despite it needing to run inside there because that's where the `thread` variable is defined. (This is why you are getting that error message, BTW.) If you fix these things (and check whether you've done other silly mistakes in the same vein), the code should work.

If you're going to copy examples from elsewhere, please copy them correctly. Randomly changing the context in which code fragments run is likely to not work well *in any programming language…*

Comment: Fair enough, the changes are only due to copy/paste from PDF getting screwy.  I'll go back again, knowing that was the problem.  Because I had to declare variables, which I don't think were declared properly, that led to the inference that the example code was flawed.  Had no idea it was a copy/paste error.

Answer (score 0):

There's something odd about copy/paste from at least this PDF, it literally puts lines in the wrong order.  I ran it through an online PDF to text converter with the same result.

Badly indented code to follow (sans comments, which don't copy well):

```
package require Tcl 8.4
package require Thread 2.5
if {$argc > 0} {
set port [lindex $argv 0]
} else {
set port 9001
}



socket -server _ClientConnect $port

proc _ClientConnect {sock host port} {

after 0 [list ClientConnect $sock $host $port]

}






proc ClientConnect {sock host port} {

set thread [thread::create {
proc ReadLine {sock} {
if {[catch {gets $sock line} len] || [eof $sock]} {
catch {close $sock}
thread::release
} elseif {$len >= 0} {
EchoLine $sock $line
}
}


proc EchoLine {sock line} {
if {[string equal -nocase $line quit]} {
SendMessage $sock \
"Closing connection to Echo server"
catch {close $sock}
thread::release
} else {
SendMessage $sock $line
}
}

proc SendMessage {sock msg} {
if {[catch {puts $sock $msg} error]} {
puts stderr "Error writing to socket: $error"
catch {close $sock}
thread::release
}
}


thread::wait
}]




thread::detach $sock


thread::send -async $thread [list set sock $sock]


thread::send -async $thread {
thread::attach $sock
fconfigure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0
fileevent $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]
SendMessage $sock "Connected to Echo server"
}

}


vwait forever
```

Too bad komodo doesn't auto-indent.  Anyhow, it seems to at least run without error.  Looking into naglfar capabilities.